# How to write cucumber test which repeat testing of login / logout multiple times based on an array of username-password?

Tags: cucumber

Could any please suggest me some way we could use cucumber to repeat a test (e.g Login/Logout) multiple time, but changing only username/password for each time?

I could do for a single pair of username/password, but I'm looking for a way to re-use the test for multiple data set (The data set may be an array which store username/password, and the expected result which is true or false).

Thanks.

Comment: Look in to Cucumber's Scenario Outlines. (But do you really need a full integration test for different usernames and passwords? Could you do it with unit tests?)

Comment: Thank you Dave, Scenario Outlines does the work. It's because my customer require to implement this test as integration test.

Answer (score 1):

`Scenario Outline` allows you to run your `Features` based on the provided `Examples` in a tabular format, so to test login multiple time with different values you instruct to your `step definition` to run for every provided `examples`, In this we need to mention table column field in angle brackets in feature file.

Scenario Outline: Creating a new account
    Given I am not authenticated
    When I go to Login page
    And I fill in "user_email" with "`<email>`"
    And I fill in "user_password" with "`<password>`"
    And I press "Sign up"
    Then I should see "logged in as `<email>`"

```
Examples:
  | email            | password   |
  | testing@xyz.com  | secretpass |
  | testing2@xyz.com | fr33z3     |
```

For more references, [Cucumber tutorials](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#scenario-outline)